# Is it possible to create a @property for an anonymous struct in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have an anonymous struct in my code that I'd like to access via an assign @property (no pointer). However, since this is an anonymous structure. Here's the cocoa code I created (even if it's cocoa code, it's relevant to objective-c in general.)

```
@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController {

    struct {
       BOOL isDeviceOwner:1;

    } _statusFlags;
}
```

Now I'd like to create a property for _statusFlags:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just define it inline where you would define the type.

`@property (nonatomic, assign) struct { ... } statusFlags;`

Then when you synthesize it you can do `@synthesize statusFlags = _statusFlags` if you really like the underscored ivars, but this will generate the ivar for you. You do not need to define it explicitly.

Comment: Oh I see.. this is more cumbersome than I expected but it's logical. as for the underscored ivars. why wouldn't I like them?

Comment: That gets into some philosophical language fun :) There has been lots of discussion about it in other threads, but my argument is there isn't any reason to access the raw ivar, all accesses should go through the property accessor.

Comment: I also get the following error with what you suggest: 
ProfileViewController.m:61: error: type of property 'statusFlags' does not match type of ivar '_statusFlags' this is what I did: 

    @property (nonatomic, assign) struct {BOOL isDeviceOwner:1;} statusFlags;

Comment: Did you remove the explicit ivar from the interface block?

Comment: Also, the only reason why I'm using _ivar is to avoid variable collision when creating function arguments

Comment: Oh.... Ok I understand now how this works. Since this is a scalar var, I prefer declaring it in the class declaration rather than in a property, for readability's sake

Comment: Then you need to give it a named type.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by making the property or method take a pointer to a struck, you then only have to let the compiler know that the struct exists but not what is in the struct i.e. the size, for example

```
struct myPrivateStruct;
...
@property(assign,nonatomic)  struct myPrivateStruct * myStructProperty;
```

the struct myPrivateStruct then has to be then defined in your implementation file and property implement the property manually for example

```
struct myPrivateStruct { int a, b; float c; };

- (void)setMyStructProperty:(struct myPrivateStruct *)aValue
{
    memcpy(&myIVar,aValue,sizeof(struct myPrivateStruct));
}
```

this is vary similar to us @class in interface files, of Objective-C class.